# Is there any way to set a class in the QMap value?

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, qmap

Is there any way to add & use a class in the QMap value?

I wanna use `QMap<QString, Aclass> map;` in Qt. and when I want to set it's value in a function, some errors appear:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1043: error: 'QWidget& QWidget::operator=(const QWidget&)' is private
     Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
            ^
```

ps: my container class is inherited from QWidget & is singleton.

```
#include "Aclass.h"
#include <QWidget>

class AmainClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static AmainClass &getInstance();
    void setApp(QString name, Aclass app);

private:
    AmainClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QMap<QString, Aclass> map;
};
```

and in .cpp:

```
void AmainClass::setApp(QString name, Aclass app)
{
    map.insert(name, app);
}
```

edit: `Aclass` is another class that is inherited from `QWidget`.

Comment: `Aclass` is derived from `QWidget` too, I assume?

Comment: Is `Aclass` that you are trying to set a child of some other widget, or is it a child of this `AmainClass` instance?

Comment: @s.m See my answer. And please add that to the question. Remember, a question should contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

All Qt Objects that are derivated from QObject cannot be copied, because the copy constructor is private. This is the error message. You could use a reference or a pointer to your object in the map

```
QMap<QString, Aclass&> map;
```

or

```
QMap<QString, Aclass*> map;
```

Then the set function should be

```
void setApp(QString name, Aclass& app){
map.insert(name, app);
}
```

When you use pointers just replace & with *

Comment: His `setApp` function has the same problem.

Comment: I try    ` QMap<QString, Aclass&> map; `  -->  error: no matching function for call to 'QMap<QString, Aclass&>::insert(QString&, Aclass*)'
     map.insert(name, &app);
                                   ^

Comment: Yeah you should also adjust that. The best thing would be to change all signatures. I edit my solution

Comment: s.m. You must use either * or &. Do not mix them together. This is errorprone and in most cases do not work

Comment: @Liachtei i just tryed &.

Comment: but in your solution you wrote map.insert(name, &app);
This is not valid. you can skip the & before app when your signature uses references.
If you are confused with the &, you should check the c++ documentation for the difference between  &, * and the smart pointers stated by the other guys

Comment: @Liachtei some errors appear:    `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore\qmap.h:416: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Aclass&'
         typedef T *pointer;
                    ^`   &   `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:1043: error: 'QWidget& QWidget::operator=(const QWidget&)' is private
     Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
            ^`     &           `C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore\qmap.h:260: error: the type being destroyed is 'Aclass', but the destructor refers to 'Aclass&'
         value.~T();
         ^`

Comment: @s.m Perhaps you should use pointers in that case. i don't know the definition auf your Aclass, but there could be a hidden problem in that class. Try replacing all & with * and use raw pointers. Notice: that you then must explicitly allocate and deallocate the memory for the objects.

Answer (score 2):

As per Qt documentation, `QObject` and classes derived from it do not support being copied: Qt's meta-object mechanism and similar infrastructure relies on pointers to `QObject`s remaining valid, which would not hold if they were copied or moved around. You therefore cannot store a `QObject` in a container by value. Use a smart pointer instead:

```
QMap<QString, std::unique_ptr<Aclass>> map;
```

The same applies to `setApp` as well, of course:

```
void AmainClass::setApp(QString name, std::unique_ptr<Aclass> app)
{
    map.insert(name, std::move(app));
}
```

Using a `std::unique_ptr` assumes three things:

1. You are using a compiler which supports that part of C++11.
2. Your version of Qt is recent enough to support move semantics.
3. You intend `map` to be the sole owner of the `Aclass` objects.

Since this is 2016, 1 & 2 should really be true by now.

As for 3, you generally need to sort out ownership (a design decision) before you choose how to implement it (a coding decision). Based on your original example, I assume you want `map` to own the `Aclass` objects, hence my use of `std::unique_ptr`.

If you instead want to use a different ownership scheme (such as using Qt's parent-child ownership relationships), you'd use different storage. For the parent-child thing, a raw pointer (or perhaps `QPointer`) would be appropriate.

Comment: your answer is something like @skypjack 's answer. I should develop std::unique_ptr in qt, shouldn't I?

Comment: This works as long as `app` is not a child of some other widget which could be destroyed before `AmainClass` instance.

Comment: @s.m What do you mean with "I should develop `std::unique_ptr` in qt"? `std::unique_ptr` is part of the standard library. Use it if your map is supposed to own the `Aclass` instance. If using a different form of ownership (such as Qt's parent-child relationships), use an appropriate pointer (such as `QPointer` or a raw pointer).

Comment: @thuga Since the OP wanted to store the class by value, I consider it quite unlikely they want a different ownership scheme.

Comment: It is hard to tell. Could be just lack of understanding of pointers and values in general. I mean storing a widget in a container by value makes no sense by itself. Also, it could be a dynamic UI where he might want to destroy some widget and replace it with another similar one. Destroying that widget before clearing the map would be disastrous. There are a lot of important details missing in the question.

Comment: @Angew because of this error:      `error: 'std::unique_ptr' has not been declared
     void setApp(QString name, std::unique_ptr<Aclass> app);`
                                             ^

Comment: @s.m `#include <memory>`. Anyway, it needs your version of Qt to support move semantics. If that's not the case, `std::shared_ptr` (same header) could be used instead. But please sort out the ownership first. I will expand the answer.

Comment: @Angew It's `Qt Creator 3.4.2 (opensource)` , `Based on Qt 5.5.0 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)` (on winows) . by the way I want to run my code on Qt4 either.

Comment: @s.m VS2013 supports `std::unique_ptr` just fine, and Qt 5.5 definitely supports move semantics. As for Qt 4 - consult the manual of the version you'd be using.

Comment: @Angew  I included `#include <stdio.h>` ,  `#include <stdlib.h>` & `#include <memory>`, but error exists.

Comment: @s.m That looks like a separate issue, really. This question is about storing `QWidget`s in containers by value, and the answer is "Cannot be done. Use some sort of pointer instead." If you're having trouble storing a specific pointer type in a `QMap`, treat it as a new problem: search, and if you fail to find anything, ask a new question, this time including a real [mcve].

Comment: @Angew thanks for you suggestion. but which part of my question wasn't  `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` ?

Comment: @s.m For a question of this kind, an MCVE should be something I can copy-paste into a file (or two), compile, and observe the error myself. In your case, the definition of `Aclass` is missing altogether, as is (most likely) `#include <QMap>`.

Comment: Solved my problem. Also;- holy shit does C++ make me want to break things sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::reference_wrapper<Aclass>` as a type for value.
Be aware anyway that you must guarantee for the lifetime of the referenced objects.
See the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) for further details.

Otherwise, you can use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr<Aclass>` or `std::shared_ptr<Aclass>`, so that lifetime will be automatically managed for you.
See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for further details about `shared_ptr`, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for `unique_ptr`.

Otherwise, far simpler, you can define the missed operator `operator=` for `Aclass`. How almost depends on your actual problem, I cannot even say if it's a viable solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this. Can you explain more?

Comment: He cannot use the `operator=` as [`QObject` prohibits this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator).